# Promisify gcloud using Bluebird promise

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, promise, bluebird, es6-promise

I want to promisify all the method in gcloud packages, but I got errors doing it.

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const gcloud = Promise.promisifyAll(require('gcloud'));

//no problem when passing a callback into it
bucket.getFiles((err, files) => {
    console.log(files)
})

//Complain error -> bucket.getFilesAsync is not a function
bucket.getFilesAsync().then((files) => {
    console.log(files)
})
```

When i called the `async` method after `promisifyAll` it complains `bucket.getFilesAsync is not a function`, so I try to promisify the method by using the ES6 promises.

```
const bucketFiles = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    bucket.getFiles((err, files) => {
        if (err) return reject(err);

        resolve(files);
    });
});

bucketFiles.then((files) => {
    console.log(files)
})
```

This promisification using the ES6 way is working , but I dont want to promisifiy each method by doing this. So, I would like to have `bluebird` to promisify everything for me.

May I know how can I promisify the gcloud package using bluebird?

Comment: What is it ``bucket``?

Comment: it is an object from [Google App Engine Cloud Storage](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-node/#/docs/v0.30.2/storage/bucket?method=getFiles])

Comment: probably you need to ``Promise.promisifyAll(bucket);``

Comment: may be ``Promise.promisifyAll(require('gcloud/lib/storage/bucket').prototype)``?

Comment: it is working when you call `Promise.promisifyAll(bucket);`, may I know why this is working but not `Promise.promisifyAll(require('gcloud'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to docs about [Promisification](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promisification.html):

> Promisifies the entire object by going through the object's properties
>   and creating an async equivalent of each function on the object and
>   its prototype chain.

So, then you promisify `gcloud` object, its nothing about promisify bucket, cause its another class.

You can do it for each instance of Bucket

```
Promise.promisifyAll(bucket);
```

Or patch prototype of Bucket once for application

```
Promise.promisifyAll(require('gcloud/lib/storage/bucket').prototype);
```